# is this normal in .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I feel it's a bug, is it?

```
decimal s = 30 / 9;
double w = 20 / 9;
Console.WriteLine(s);
Console.WriteLine(w);
```

and the result is

[image]

Comment: It is the default behavior in all .net versions, *integer division*: `30 / 9 == 3; 30 % 9 == 3` (here `%` stands for remainder), if you want *decimal*, put it as `30m / 9m`, in case of `double` - `20.0 / 9.0`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this normal, yes. Is this a bug, no.

You're doing integer math on `30 / 9` which is `3` and then assigning to a `decimal` which then does the conversion. Same with the second line.

Try this instead:

```
decimal s = 30m / 9m;
double w = 20.0 / 9.0;
Console.WriteLine(s);
Console.WriteLine(w);
```

That gives:

```
3.3333333333333333333333333333
2.2222222222222223
```

You need to declare your constants in your expression with the correct type. Suffix an `m` for `decimal`. And either provide a decimal place or suffix with a `d` for `double`.

Comment: Console.WriteLine(s.ToString("N2"));  //  3.33

Comment: Console.WriteLine(w.ToString("N4")); //  2.2222

Comment: @Gezgalee - Why?

Comment: I'm very happy to talk to a professional like you. My intention in writing the comment was just to show the user that the output can be filtered that way. I did not intend to be bold and I apologize to you if I upset you. I wish you good health and success. @Enigmativity

Comment: @Gezgalee - It's no problem - I just didn't understand why you were trying suggest formatting the value. I didn't think it helped make the situation clearer in any way.